# Hashtable Parameter Acting Like Reference Variable

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

It seems like if you pass a hashtable as a parameter to a function and modify the variable that the function has created for that hashtable, the original variable gets modified too.  So the hashtable paramater is acting like a reference variable.  Why is this?

Example that will probably explain this better:

```
function testParams ([hashtable]$hashParam, [string]$strParam) {
    $hashParam.Remove('a')
    $strParam = "I am a string"
}


$str = "a string"

$ht = @{}
$ht['a'] = 'aaaa'
$ht['b'] = 'bbbb'
$ht['c'] = 'cccc'

testParams $ht $string

Write-Host $str
Write-Host "$($ht | Out-String)"
```

...And that will output:

```
a string

Name                           Value
----                           -----
c                              cccc
b                              bbbb
```

Edit:  Just found a simpler example:

```
$ht = @{}
$ht[1] = '1111'
$ht[2] = '2222'

$htCopy = $ht
$htCopy.Remove(1)

$ht
```

Which would output:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
2                              2222
```

Comment: This is by design, as explained [here](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebookv2/archive/2012/02/07/chapter-4-arrays-and-hashtables.aspx#copying-arrays-and-hash-tables).

Comment: Thanks you @AlexanderObersht!  For some reason I could not find information on that.  Thank you, kind sir.